# Java - Add an object to an arraylist, then adding another to the arraylist causes the first element to be overwritten

Tags: java, arraylist, overwrite

I'm currently doing my third year programming project and its a folio tracker. :/ I have crated Stock_API and Portfolio_API interfaces (and implementations of them) and a GUI class which when instantiated takes two parameters as so:

```
public GUI(Portfolio_API p, Stock s){
      tempPort = p;
      tempStock = s;
}
```

I use this constructor as a way of getting implementations of these interfaces into the GUI without exposing the implementation to the  GUI (which is one of the main objectives of this project). A portfolio object has a name(string) and an ArrayList. A stock object has a ticker symbol(string), a stock name(string), a share value(float), a number of shares(int) and a value of holding(float).

In the GUI i have a portCollection array list which holds objects of type portfolio_API and this is so the system can keep track of multiple portfolios. Also as mentioned in the block of code above has a tempStock and tempPort object.

Sorry to give u so much detail about the program but i thought it best so i could get the context across. Anyway, the problem at hand. I have a method which uses the GUI to get a ticker symbol, a stock name and a number of shares and adds the stock to the current portfolio open(each portfolio has its own tab). The method looks like this:

```
public void addStock() {
    int num_shares = 0;
    float dailyChange = 0.0f;
    float stockValue = 0.0f;
    boolean succeed = true;

    // GUI gets information of stock from user
    String ticker = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter the ticker symbol:");
    String stockName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter the Stock name:");
    try {
        num_shares = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Enter the number of shares:"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Number of shares was not an integer. Try again");
        succeed = false;
    }

    // If parsing was successful...
    if (succeed) {
        tempStock.setTicker(ticker);
        tempStock.setNumberOfShares(num_shares);
        tempStock.setStockName(stockName);

        // Fetches newest value using the current ticker symbol
        boolean succeedUpdate = tempStock.updateShareValue();

        if (succeedUpdate) {
            tempStock.calculateValueOfHolding();

            // Adds to the current portfolio...
            String tabName = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(tabbedPane
                    .getSelectedIndex());
            System.out.println(tabName);
            findPortfolio(tabName).addStock(tempStock);
            findPortfolio(tabName).sort();

            // ...Then adds it to the table
            JPanel j = (JPanel) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent()
                    .getComponentAt(0, 0);
            JViewport v = ((JScrollPane)   j.getComponent(0)).getViewport();
            JTable table = (JTable) v.getComponent(0);

            float currentTotal = findPortfolio(tabName).getTotal();

            // Updates the total label
            ((JLabel) j.getComponent(1)).setText("Total: " + currentTotal);

            Object[] newStock = { tempStock.getTicker(),
                    tempStock.getStockName(),
                    tempStock.getNumberOfShares(),
                    tempStock.getShareValue(),
                    tempStock.getValueOfHolding() };
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(newStock);
        }
    }
}
```

When I add more than one stock, the new stock takes place of the old one an effectively overwrites it.  I think its the reuse of tempStock that is doing it. Not sure why though as surely if i add the variable to an arraylist it becomes part of that arraylist and needs no association with the tempStock variable?

Methods that are used with the mentioned arraylists :

```
private Portfolio_API findPortfolio(String name) {
        Portfolio_API p = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < portCollection.size(); i++) {
            if (portCollection.get(i).getName() == name) {
                p = portCollection.get(i);
            }
        }
```

These two are in the Portfolio class:

```
@Override
public boolean addStock(Stock_API s) {
    if (!doesExist(s)) {
        portfolio.add(s);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean doesExist(Stock_API s) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < portfolio.size(); i++) {
        if (portfolio.get(i).getTicker() == s.getTicker()) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

I've only come here for help because i have hit a brick wall and I really need help. If anyone could give me any suggestions, i'd be eternally in your debt.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You haven't shown any code which uses an `ArrayList`, which makes it hard to pin this down...

Comment: Ah sorry, will edit the post and add a few methods that use an arraylist.

Comment: When you "add" an object to a list, you add a reference to that object, not a copy of the object.  If you later change the object, all references to that object will see that change.

Comment: Thanks, i thought thats what was happening but wasnt sure. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you are right when you say you think it's because you're reusing the `tempStock` variable. This variable still references the original object so calling `setTicker()` etc on `tempStock` also changes the object referenced by your `ArrayList` because it's the same object. Try reinitialising your `tempStock` and see if it makes a difference:

```
// If parsing was successful...
    if (succeed) {
        tempStock = new Stock(); // or however you instantiate this object
        tempStock.setTicker(ticker);
        tempStock.setNumberOfShares(num_shares);
        tempStock.setStockName(stockName);
```

Comment: I would but by re initialising i would have to do tempStock = new Stock(); but this would expose the implementation to the GUI :/ I wish there was a way to do tempStock = new Stock_API() but of course being an interface, you cant initailise it.

Comment: You could overload the `Portfolio` class's `addStock()` to take the stock data `addStock(Ticker ticker, int numOfShares, String name)` and build it in there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all your input. @oracle certified professor helped with the stock problems after adding an overloaded method for addStock but turned out the same problems plagued portfolio.

What I did was create a makePortfolio method in Portfolio_API to create a new portfolio and return it. That way it avoids any nasty overwrite, gonna add it to stock too just now.

Thanks again guys. Good night! :)